# Translate Sap Fiori launchpad tile number unit

Tags: numbers, translate, tile, sap-fiori

Is there a way to translate the number unit of a dynamic SAP Fiori launchpad tile?

[image: Here is what I mean]

Where can someone find this object and translate it?

Is it even a translatable text?

Has anybody succeeded in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display_number_unit is technically only stored in the Configuration of Tiles and is not translatable.
Please see also Table 1 (General) in the corresponding documentation here: [Dynamic App Launcher Tiles](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/92/dda11afc814a538a8ec626f4a74c8d/frameset.htm).

Comment: Is your text “Pending Items” really a number unit or could it be an information?
In this case it should be translatable.
You might verify this in the configuration of the tile.
Do you configure your FLP in the cloud or in ABAP?